# Convolution theorem problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

Use the convolution theorem to show that
$$\int_{0}^1 u^m(1-u)^ndu = \frac{m!n!}{(m+n+1)!}$$
I don't know where to start on this, do I have you use commutative property of convolution?

Comment: Do you know what the convolution theorem is?

Comment: yes, it`s integral from 0 to t of ( f(u) * g(t-u) )du

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site please consider learning to typeset in MathJax as images with formulas in questions and answers is sometimes frowned upon.

Comment: @Heyo That is convolution, not convolution theorem.

Comment: I solved it, thanks for forwarding me to look up for the theorem. I knew it just did not think it is considered a theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I(m,n)$ be LHS and $J(m,n)$ be RHS of equality. We have $I(m,0)=J(m,0)=\frac1{m+1}$
Integrating by parts gives $I(m,n)=\frac{n}{m+1}I(m+1,n-1).$

It is evident that $J(m,n)=\frac{n}{m+1}J(m+1,n-1).$
So $I$ and $J$ have the same recursion formula and the same anitial conditions 
$I(m,0)=J(m,0)$. Therefore they must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

With the substitution $u=e^{-x}$ the problem boils down to finding
$$ I(m,n) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}(1-e^{-x})^m e^{-(n+1)x}\,dx $$
that for a fixed $m\in\mathbb{N}$, due to the binomial theorem, equals
$$ g(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{n+1+k}=\frac{m!}{(m+n+1)(m+n)\cdots(1+n)} $$
where the last identity follows from the fact that $\frac{m!}{(m+n+1)(m+n)\cdots(1+n)}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{n+1+k}$ share the same simple poles and the same residues.